# setState causing memory leak inside subject subscribe

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, react-navigation

I am facing error while navigating to `TestPage` second time. The code is working fine for first navigation, but I am getting error on second navigation.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

I have notices that the error does not occur if I remove the setinterval block.

The data from observable is reflecting fine in `Text`, but I am not able to understand what is causing this error. Hence my question here is why the setState is not working inside observable subscribe?

```js
export const testSubject = new Subject<any>();
setInterval(() => {
    testSubject.next({ dest: 'any', msg: [] });
}, 2000);

function TestPage({ route, navigation }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);

    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            testSubject.subscribe(({ dest, msg }) => {
                setData(msg);
            });
            return () => _cleanup();
        }, []),
    );

    const _cleanup = () => {};

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>
            <Button
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('home');
                }}
                title="back"
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default TestPage;
```

Comment: Do you need to unsubscribe from `testSubject` when the component unmounts? (*or close the stream?*)

Comment: no. that subject is being used in multiple components. I have shown here just a representation of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is `useFocusEffect(useCallback(...))`, but I will assume it's the equivalent of a regular `useEffect`.

The problem you have is that you're not cleaning up the subscription to the stream when the component unmounts. When there's a new update on `testSubject`, the old instance (which unmounted) will call `setData()` on an unmount component, and react will complain.

Why does that `_cleanup` function does nothing? You just need to complete it:

```
    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            const subscription = testSubject.subscribe(({ dest, msg }) => {
                setData(msg);
            });
            return () => {
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            }
        }, []),
    );
```

This should work.

Comment: I dont want to unsubscribe the subject. the subject is global and being used by different components. If I unsubscribe it as above, other components stop working. Also, according to ur ans, react should throw error every time after first call, but it is just throwing the error once and it works as expected afterwards.

Comment: Notice that I didn't do `testSubject.unsubscribe()`. This as you said, it would close the subject and no one would be able to use it. What I did is close the subscription of this particular component to the testSubject. I suggest you to try it (unsubscribing from the `subscription`, not the `testSubject`) and you'll see how this solves your issue without actually closing the subject

Comment: React only shows that warning once to not be spammy. It's a warning, not an error, it's just to tell you that you might have subscriptions open where you needed to close them, but react will continue working just fine (but you have a memory leak)